# When is it appropriate to model data as a Stochastic Process?

Tags: modeling, prediction, terminology, stochastic-processes

I understand the question may be poorly worded, but please bear with me.

I have a background in computer science and mathematics, but never took any upper-level statistics courses. I currently work as a data scientist.

Recently, I have run into data I believe can be modeled as stochastic processes. For instance, I am currently working on a project where I am trying to predict the time it will take for various teams (ie, networking team, software development team) to finish a project they are given, given historical data. I believe this is a stochastic process because we know the length of each past project in days, and each project is indexed by time.

Similarly, I attempted to model some employment data using Markov Chains, where the history of someone's employment with my company (ie, promotions, lay offs, etc.) were the nodes in the chain.

**My questions:**

i) How can we know when we can model data as a stochastic process?

ii) Furthermore, if something *is* a stochastic process, how can I know which *kind* of stochastic process it is and what properties it has? It is my understanding that there are various kinds and "families".

iii) Finally, when we know something is a stochastic process, and we know its properties, when is it appropriate to use methods meant for the analysis of stochastic processes instead of attempting to model the data in a different way (ie, with a liner regression).

Thank you!